# How to convert a Pyglet image to a PIL image?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, pyglet

i want to convert a Pyglet.AbstractImage object to an PIL image for further manipulation
here are my codes

```
from pyglet import image
from PIL import Image
pic = image.load('pic.jpg')
data = pic.get_data('RGB', pic.pitch)
im = Image.fromstring('RGB', (pic.width, pic.height), data)
im.show()
```

but the image shown went wrong.
so how to convert an image from pyglet to PIL properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I find the solution

the pitch in Pyglet.AbstractImage instance is not compatible with PIL
I found in pyglet 1.1 there is a codec function to encode the Pyglet image to PIL
here is the [link](http://pyglet.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/pyglet/image/codecs/pil.py) to the source

so the code above should be modified to this

```
from pyglet import image
from PIL import Image
pic = image.load('pic.jpg')
pitch = -(pic.width * len('RGB'))
data = pic.get_data('RGB', pitch) # using the new pitch
im = Image.fromstring('RGB', (pic.width, pic.height), data)
im.show()
```

I'm using a 461x288 image in this case and find that pic.pitch is -1384

but the new pitch is -1383

Answer (score 0):

This is an open [wishlist](http://code.google.com/p/pyglet/wiki/ReleaseSchedule) item:

> AbstractImage to/from PIL image.